# How to select Unique value with some condition for mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here how my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT,user_id VARCHAR(5),add_date date);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES
  (1, 100, '2014-07-22'),
  (2, 400, '2014-07-22'),
  (3, 500, '2014-07-22'),
  (4, 500, '2014-07-22'),
  (5, 200, '2014-07-21'),
  (6, 300, '2014-07-21'),
  (7, 100, '2014-07-20'),
  (8, 200, '2014-07-20');
```

Initially i need to check the query date between 2014-07-21 to 2014-07-22 and Group by user_id , 
 i got

```
**user_id** |  **add_date** 
        100 | 2014-07-22 
        400 | 2014-07-22
        500 | 2014-07-22
        200 | 2014-07-21
        300 | 2014-07-21
```

Then more , i need to check full data this table.this user id unique or not ? except date condition.

```
**Require Answer:**
 **user_id** |  **add_date**
         400 | 2014-07-22
         500 | 2014-07-22
         300 | 2014-07-21
```

**Note:**

I need single query.

Comment: Your conditions directly translate into SQL `where`, `group by`, and `having` clauses.  Are you familiar with the language?

Comment: i know...but just explain english.that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   user_id, 
   max(add_date) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING -- no date outside of the requested range
   MIN(add_date) BETWEEN '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22'
AND 
   MAX(add_date) BETWEEN '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   count(user_id) as c 
from 
   my_table 
having 
   c = 1 
   and add_date between '2014-07-21' 
   and '2014-07-22' 
group by 
   user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table against itself with a LEFT OUTER JOIN for the matching user id, but where the dates do not match. Group by the user id and date, and use having to check that there are no matching user:-

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.add_date
FROM my_table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
AND a.add_date != b.add_date
WHERE a.add_date between '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22'
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.add_date
HAVING COUNT(b.user_id) = 0
```

If you are only interested in duplicates within the date range then check for the date range of the 2nd copy of the table in the ON clause as well

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.add_date
FROM my_table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
AND a.add_date != b.add_date
AND b.add_date between '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22'
WHERE a.add_date between '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22'
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.add_date
HAVING COUNT(b.user_id) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are actually a little hard to follow.  I think the following does what you want:

```
select user_id, max(add_date)
from my_table
group by user_id
having max(add_date) between '2014-07-21' and '2014-07-22' and
       count(*) = 1;
```

It is unclear what this is supposed to mean:  "except date condition."